# How to make these XSLT results delimited

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

This XML sample

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy -->
<catalog>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Virgin records</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1990</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Eros</title>
    <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>BMG</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1997</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>One night only</title>
    <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1998</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Sylvias Mother</title>
    <artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS</company>
    <price>8.10</price>
    <year>1973</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Maggie May</title>
    <artist>Rod Stewart</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Pickwick</company>
    <price>8.50</price>
    <year>1990</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Romanza</title>
    <artist>Andrea Bocelli</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>10.80</price>
    <year>1996</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>When a man loves a woman</title>
    <artist>Percy Sledge</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Atlantic</company>
    <price>8.70</price>
    <year>1987</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Black angel</title>
    <artist>Savage Rose</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Mega</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1995</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>1999 Grammy Nominees</title>
    <artist>Many</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Grammy</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1999</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>For the good times</title>
    <artist>Kenny Rogers</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Mucik Master</company>
    <price>8.70</price>
    <year>1995</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Big Willie style</title>
    <artist>Will Smith</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1997</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Tupelo Honey</title>
    <artist>Van Morrison</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>8.20</price>
    <year>1971</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Soulsville</title>
    <artist>Jorn Hoel</artist>
    <country>Norway</country>
    <company>WEA</company>
    <price>7.90</price>
    <year>1996</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>The very best of</title>
    <artist>Cat Stevens</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Island</company>
    <price>8.90</price>
    <year>1990</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Stop</title>
    <artist>Sam Brown</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>A and M</company>
    <price>8.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Bridge of Spies</title>
    <artist>T`Pau</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Siren</company>
    <price>7.90</price>
    <year>1987</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Private Dancer</title>
    <artist>Tina Turner</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Capitol</company>
    <price>8.90</price>
    <year>1983</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Midt om natten</title>
    <artist>Kim Larsen</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Medley</company>
    <price>7.80</price>
    <year>1983</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Pavarotti Gala Concert</title>
    <artist>Luciano Pavarotti</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>DECCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1991</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>The dock of the bay</title>
    <artist>Otis Redding</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Atlantic</company>
    <price>7.90</price>
    <year>1987</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Picture book</title>
    <artist>Simply Red</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Elektra</company>
    <price>7.20</price>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Red</title>
    <artist>The Communards</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>London</company>
    <price>7.80</price>
    <year>1987</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Unchain my heart</title>
    <artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>EMI</company>
    <price>8.20</price>
    <year>1987</year>
</cd>
```

Produces these results -

> Empire Burlesque Bob Dylan USA Columbia 10.90 1985 Hide your heart
>   Bonnie Tyler UK CBS Records 9.90 1988 Greatest Hits Dolly Parton USA
>   RCA 9.90 1982 Still got the blues Gary Moore UK Virgin records 10.20
>   1990 Eros Eros Ramazzotti EU BMG 9.90 1997 One night only Bee Gees UK
>   Polydor 10.90 1998 Sylvias Mother Dr.Hook UK CBS 8.10 1973 Maggie May
>   Rod Stewart UK Pickwick 8.50 1990 Romanza Andrea Bocelli EU Polydor
>   10.80 1996 When a man loves a woman Percy Sledge USA Atlantic 8.70 1987 Black angel Savage Rose EU Mega 10.90 1995 1999 Grammy Nominees
>   Many USA Grammy 10.20 1999 For the good times Kenny Rogers UK Mucik
>   Master 8.70 1995 Big Willie style Will Smith USA Columbia 9.90 1997
>   Tupelo Honey Van Morrison UK Polydor 8.20 1971 Soulsville Jorn Hoel
>   Norway WEA 7.90 1996 The very best of Cat Stevens UK Island 8.90 1990
>   Stop Sam Brown UK A and M 8.90 1988 Bridge of Spies T`Pau UK Siren
>   7.90 1987 Private Dancer Tina Turner UK Capitol 8.90 1983 Midt om natten Kim Larsen EU Medley 7.80 1983 Pavarotti Gala Concert Luciano
>   Pavarotti UK DECCA 9.90 1991 The dock of the bay Otis Redding USA
>   Atlantic 7.90 1987 Picture book Simply Red EU Elektra 7.20 1985 Red
>   The Communards UK London 7.80 1987 Unchain my heart Joe Cocker USA EMI
>   8.20 1987

Using this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates/>  
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Question is how do I comma delimit the results from this XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet outputs all the text nodes from your input XML, the contents of one `cd`element on each line, separated by commas.

The following condition

```
<xsl:if test="position() != last()">
```

ensures that no comma is put at the end of a line. You did not say explicitly that this is a requirement, I am just guessing it is. A further refinement could be to keep the stylesheet from outputtting a newline character at the very end of the output text.

**Stylesheet (edited as suggested by @michael.hor257k)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="catalog">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cd">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Output**

```
Empire Burlesque,Bob Dylan,USA,Columbia,10.90,1985
Hide your heart,Bonnie Tyler,UK,CBS Records,9.90,1988
Greatest Hits,Dolly Parton,USA,RCA,9.90,1982
Still got the blues,Gary Moore,UK,Virgin records,10.20,1990
Eros,Eros Ramazzotti,EU,BMG,9.90,1997
One night only,Bee Gees,UK,Polydor,10.90,1998
Sylvias Mother,Dr.Hook,UK,CBS,8.10,1973
Maggie May,Rod Stewart,UK,Pickwick,8.50,1990
Romanza,Andrea Bocelli,EU,Polydor,10.80,1996
When a man loves a woman,Percy Sledge,USA,Atlantic,8.70,1987
Black angel,Savage Rose,EU,Mega,10.90,1995
1999 Grammy Nominees,Many,USA,Grammy,10.20,1999
For the good times,Kenny Rogers,UK,Mucik Master,8.70,1995
Big Willie style,Will Smith,USA,Columbia,9.90,1997
Tupelo Honey,Van Morrison,UK,Polydor,8.20,1971
Soulsville,Jorn Hoel,Norway,WEA,7.90,1996
The very best of,Cat Stevens,UK,Island,8.90,1990
Stop,Sam Brown,UK,A and M,8.90,1988
Bridge of Spies,T`Pau,UK,Siren,7.90,1987
Private Dancer,Tina Turner,UK,Capitol,8.90,1983
Midt om natten,Kim Larsen,EU,Medley,7.80,1983
Pavarotti Gala Concert,Luciano Pavarotti,UK,DECCA,9.90,1991
The dock of the bay,Otis Redding,USA,Atlantic,7.90,1987
Picture book,Simply Red,EU,Elektra,7.20,1985
Red,The Communards,UK,London,7.80,1987
Unchain my heart,Joe Cocker,USA,EMI,8.20,1987
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was attempting to do, new line also-  thank you!

Comment: @MathiasMüller  IMHO, your second template should match on `*`. This seems to be a DB output and there's no guarantee that an element cannot be empty. Also, testing for `position()!=last()` is probably more efficient (and certainly more readable) than testing for the existence of following sibling. -- P.S. Welcome back!

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes, that is a more robust solution, I had to add another template for `catalog`. Edited the post. P.S. Thanks! In a way, I am learning the ropes again - as you can see :-).

Comment: "*I had to add another template*" This is a good example of a case where `xsl:for-each` has the advantage.

Answer (score 0):

If you need delimited output then you have to write the XSLT for handling the nodes and with text as the output in XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="catalog"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="catalog">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="cd"/>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="company"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Actually, you do not need to be so specific, **1** because built-in templates already match `/`and `catalog`and **2** because the child elements of `cd`are already in the right order.